# 'Could not autowire field' exception in Spring

Tags: spring, domain-driven-design

I have a [Spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) application and am using Spring version 3.0.4.
When I start the server it shows me an error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.domain.Custom org.controller.CustomController.custom; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.domain.Custom] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:381)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
```

#### Code for the domain class

```
@Entity
@Configurable
@Table(name="tbltest")
public class Custom implements Serializable{

    @Autowired
    public transient CustomRepository customRepository;

    public static CustomRepository getRepository() {
        CustomRepository repository = new Custom().CustomRepository;
        return repository;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public static Custom find(final Long id) {
        return getRepository().find(id);
    }
}
```

#### Included configurations in application context

```
<context:load-time-weaver/>
<context:spring-configured />
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.domain.custom"/>
```

#### Code for my test class:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void testCreateNew() {
    Custom registration = new Custom("ttt");
    Custom.find(1l);
    registration.persist();
    Assert.assertEquals(true, registration.getId() > 0);
}
```

#### Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/custom")
public class CustomController
{
    @Autowired
    public Custom Custom;
}
```

And I have added `spring-instrument.jar` for the VM argument.

Comment: Could you please explain the relation between "domain driven design" and the exception. -- the title of you question is very confusing

Comment: I agree with @Ralph. This has nothing to do with domain driven design.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you forgot to add

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.domain" />
```

to your application-context.xml so that spring knows where to scan for your `@Component` annotations. Just enabling `<context:annotation-config />` is not enough.

Comment: @Romani: what do you mean: The component scan is configured for the package but you did not posted it in the question (then update the question) or did it solved the problem?

Comment: I updated it in the question.. in my application,it was already written in application context still it is giving error

Comment: `<context:component-scan base-package="org.testpkg.proj"/>`
is not the same package as `org.domain.Custom`. You need to be exact because it is very probable that this is the problem.